# Amazon SimpleEmail: how to check if an Email has been delivered?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I tried to send emails with Amazon SES, with the Java AWS SDK, and it worked. I would like to be able to check (at a later time) whether the delivery was successful. I will define it successful if the final mailserver accepted the mail for delivery.

I saw that when you send an email you can get a messageId that uniquely identifies your email:

```
    SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest(from, destination, message);
    SendEmailResult result = service.sendEmail(request);
    String messageId = result.getMessageId();
```

However I saw that you can get only aggregated statistics, for example with SendDataPoint (Represents sending statistics data. Each SendDataPoint contains statistics for a 15-minute period of sending activity).

I'm not using SES to send bulk emails, but personalized notifications on a very low volume and I'd be interested to check every single message.

Did I overlook something? Is it possible to do this type of check with SES?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon does provide a mechanism for you to capture bounces, which provides you with contrapositive verification.

You can create a mailbox to receive bounce notifications, then tell SES to forward bounce notifications there.  e.g.:

```
request.setReturnPath("bounces@example.com");
```

You can then write code to periodically check that mailbox, and parse the messages for the destination email address.

Amazon provides a brief explanation of how they handle bounces & complaints here:

http://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/#37

However, if you want to check if the message avoided the spam filter or was read by the end user, that is beyond the scope of SES (although they work hard to ensure deliverability).

Comment: Thankyou Carter Page, that's a pity, since they intercept the bounces, so in theory they could do the extra step. I know that once the email is delivered to the remote mailserver, what is done internally there we can't know. An alternative approach I could take is to check if the user has clicked on the link with the document they are supposed to view. I think for now I will just send the bounces to my mailbox since it's just low volume and concentrate to finish other parts of the application. Thank you again!

Comment: So is the answer: No, Amazon SES does not allow email delivery detection?

Answer (score 3):

We use [Bouncely.com](http://bouncely.com). You simply set the `ReturnPath` to `bounces@bouncely.com` and it tracks all the bounces and spam reports. It also has an API that allows us to unsubscribe users automatically.

Comment: **Update:** Seems that this service is down.

Answer (score 0):

Use Amazon Simple Notification Service and define an HTTP endpoint to receive notification in case of email bounces. Works perfectly.